# Save image with ocaml graphics

Tags: graphics, ocaml

i want to save the picture generated by ocaml graphics in a file (png or jpeg).
Thank you.

Comment: which environment are you using give clear details

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to assume that you are talking about the `Graphics` module in ocaml.

You should notice that the `Graphics` module isn't for creating and processing images. You can of course call `Graphics.dump_image` if you've already gone ahead and wrote something that produces the `Graphics.image` type. This will produce a `color array array`, where `color` is a packed integer in the format, 0xRRGGBB.

After some other conversion functions you should call upon [camlimages](http://pauillac.inria.fr/camlimages/) to produce your image, and [there is a code sample from another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612886/how-to-read-a-bitmap-in-ocaml).

Comment: You said "You should notice that the Graphics module isn't for creating and processing images." Could you explain why ?

Comment: It is a platform independent module for manipulating a canvas on screen. The module is linked with native graphic primitives of the OS. That is the limit to the scope of the module. If it included image file format IO (via external libraries) that would be another dependency that they didn't want to include.

Comment: Ok i've installed camlimage but i don't find any documentation about it.

Comment: You'll have to be more specific; the total of documentation is the website linked and it's examples, the `.mli` files in the installation, and the `doc` folder in the tar ball.