# Save a drawing made by OCaml graphics in a EPS and PDF file

Tags: graphics, pdf-generation, ocaml, eps

I made an OCaml program that draws L-systems using the turtle interpretation.
What I'm looking for is to save what I draw with graphics to an image of EPS and PDF file.
But I never done this before and I don't know how to do, so I've looked in graphics librairy and  all I've found is **get_image** to get an Image file and **dump_image** to get an matrix color from an Image file but from here I don't know how to save the data into a EPS or PDF file.

Does anybody have an idea about how to do that?

Comment: What about dumping image and generating pdf using latex? For dumping you can read accepted answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236196/save-image-with-ocaml-graphics).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I never used it, but there is [graphicspdf](https://github.com/johnwhitington/graphicspdf) which implements the `Graphics` interface but outputs to PDF (`opam install graphicspdf`). Similar for postscript is [GraphPS](http://pauillac.inria.fr/graphps/) (not packaged in opam).

Alternatively if you program is well designed you should be able to render to multiple backends. In that case [Vg](http://erratique.ch/software/vg) allows you to render to PDF, SVG or the html canvas (`opam install vg`). There is also [ocaml-cairo](https://github.com/Chris00/ocaml-cairo) that provides you bindings to the C library libcairo and allows you to render to multiple rendering backends (`opam install cairo`).

Comment: Thank you so much that library works perfectly for creating PDF files froms Graphics drawing.
I also need to generate a EPS or hphl file , do you have any idea for that?

Comment: Added a link to graphps.