# camlimages - Fatal error: exception Failure("unsupported")

Tags: ocaml

My system is `3.11.0-24-generic #41-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jun 9 20:36:00 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

I successfully installed camlimages.

Then I took the example:

```
let () =
  let img = Rgb24.create 1 1 in
  Rgb24.set img 0 0 { Color.r = 255; g = 0; b = 0 };
  Jpeg.save "sample.jpg" [] (Images.Rgb24 img)
```

Then I used

```
ocamlbuild -use-ocamlfind -package camlimages -package camlimages.jpeg test.native
```

to compile and it was successful as well.

finally, when I tried to run `./test.native`, it says

```
Fatal error: exception Failure("unsupported")
```

---

Why? How to fix?

By the way, after I used opam install, it didn't give any error but if I try to `-package camlimages.all`, then it says I don't have `camlimages.freetype`, why?

---

I did `ocamlfind list | grep camlimages`, it shows:

```
camlimages          (version: 4.1.1)
camlimages.all      (version: 4.1.1)
camlimages.all_formats (version: 4.1.1)
camlimages.core     (version: 4.1.1)
camlimages.exif     (version: 4.1.1)
camlimages.gif      (version: 4.1.1)
camlimages.graphics (version: 4.1.1)
camlimages.jpeg     (version: 4.1.1)
camlimages.png      (version: 4.1.1)
camlimages.ps       (version: 4.1.1)
camlimages.tiff     (version: 4.1.1)
camlimages.xpm      (version: 4.1.1)
```

---

After turn on the debug, now it shows

```
Raised by primitive operation at file "jpeg.ml", line 152, characters 6-308
Called from file "test.ml", line 5, characters 2-46
```

Comment: compile with bytecode and add "OCAMLRUNPARAM='b'" to your environment to see where that very unhelpful message is coming from.

Comment: Could you verify that this (from my comment) works?, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612886/how-to-read-a-bitmap-in-ocaml

Comment: @nlucaroni I tried `ocamlbuild -use-ocamlfind -package camlimages -package camlimages.jpeg -cflag -g test.byte` and when run with OCAMLRUNPARAM=b, it says `(Cannot print stack backtrace: program not linked with -g)
`

Comment: @nlucaroni `Could you verify that this (from my comment) works?, stackoverflow.com/questions/612886/…` what do you mean?

Comment: @nlucaroni you mean I check the package name? I use `opam` to install it and opam listed camlimages package

Comment: For the debug option, you can add in your `_tags` file `debug:true`, or on the commandline, `-tags debug`.

Comment: no I meant compile the code example. Do you have the third-party libraries for jpg manipulation?

Comment: @nlucaroni I think I don't have `camlimages.bmp` and that's the cause?

Comment: @nlucaroni why I lack some packages after `opam install`? I guess those lackings are the cause?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`camlimages` has a number of different file-types it supports, all optionally. You'll have to install them before you install camlimages from opam. From the ubuntu repositories you can install the following,

```
libpng12-dev libjpeg-dev libtiff-dev libxpm-dev libfreetype6-dev libgif-dev
```

OPAM has a new depext field but I guess it hasn't been updated for camlimages --or maybe not appropriate since these are optional packages. You can see an example of this on the [gsl opam](https://github.com/ocaml/opam-repository/blob/master/packages/gsl/gsl.1.15.4/opam) files.

Comment: after I apt-get those libs, problems are gone, thanks to nlucaroni and the author of camlimages

Comment: What needs to be installed on OSX?

Comment: For OSX, these packages can be installed via homebrew...

 brew install libpng libjpeg libtiff